# Likelihood of a sample prediction in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, prediction

I know some machine learning algorithms can output the probability of predicted labels of an input sample.

For example, give a sample with three possible labels, a probability tuple (0.2,0.3,0.5) can be outputted through some probabilistic learning algorithms, such as logistic regression or probability estimate tree. Then the label with maximum probability (here 0.5) is outputted as the final prediction.

My question is, given a new sample having the predicted probability tuple (0.3,0.4,0.3), how can I quantitatively determine the likelihood of that the predicted label (here the second label) is correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

(This IMHO question doesn't belong here. It does belong to stat stack exchange)

The answer is freakingly simple: the probability/likelihood -- which is not exactly the same -- is `0.4`, which is pretty low.

If you want to run a small experiment. Build/learn a model classify a few instances and compare it to the ground truth. In addition sum up the probability of the most likely label. You will see that the sum of probabilities matches the fraction of correctly classified instances
or:

1. your model is wrong
2. your sample set is to small